# MBR2GPT failing with "Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 0"

Tags: windows-10, uefi, gpt

I'm trying to use `MBR2GPT` to convert an MBR/BIOS disk to GPT/UEFI. I'm getting the error `Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 0`. I found this in `setupact.log`:

```
GetOSDeviceVolume: Cannot get NT path for entry.[gle=0x000000ea]
FindOSPartitions: Cannot get volume name for the recovery boot entry. Error: 0x000000EA[gle=0x000000ea]
Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 0[gle=0x000000ea]
```

My OS is a recent Windows 10 version. It might be a Windows 7 upgrade, and the disk has been resized in the past with `gparted`. This is in a VM with a snapshot, so I can run risky commands and revert without any problems.

Command I'm running:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>MBR2GPT.EXE /convert /allowfullos

MBR2GPT will now attempt to convert the default book disk.
If conversion is successful the disk can only be booted in GPT mode.
These changes cannot be undone!

MBR2GPT: Attempting to convert disk 0
MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 0
```

Complete `setupact.log`:

```
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT was explicitly asked to run in full OS mode.
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT: System disk number is 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT: Attempting to convert disk 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT: Initial partition information
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===========================================================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         Partition layout for disk: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         Partition style          : MBR
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR signature: 53033256
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         Number of partitions     : 3
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Number: 1
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Type: 7
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Boot: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Style: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Offset: 1048576
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Length: 524288000
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Drive: None
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition1
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Number: 2
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Type: 7
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Boot: No
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Style: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Offset: 525336576
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Length: 79455782912
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Drive: C:\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition2
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Number: 3
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Type: 39
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Boot: No
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Style: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Offset: 79982622720
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Length: 542868480
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-00f8-559f12000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Drive: None
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition3
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===========================================================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ESP partition size will be 104857600
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         BCD: Opening store. Flags: 0x0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         BCD: Store path: "\??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Boot\BCD"
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         BCD: Loaded hive at BCD00000000
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         BCD: Opening object {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         FindOSPartitions: Default boot entry: {001E9BBC-213D-11EB-B4BB-F2D0CE0F2B87}
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         BCD: Opening object {001e9bbc-213d-11eb-b4bb-f2d0ce0f2b87}
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         VERBOSE: Device path: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         VERBOSE: Dos path: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume2
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         FindOSPartitions: Volume name for the default boot entry: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         BCD: Opening object {1cac28c7-213d-11eb-8bd4-98ea449f7573}
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Error                        GetOSDeviceVolume: Cannot get NT path for entry.[gle=0x000000ea]
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Error                        FindOSPartitions: Cannot get volume name for the recovery boot entry. Error: 0x000000EA[gle=0x000000ea]
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Error                        Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 0[gle=0x000000ea]
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR2GPT: Partition information at error point
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===========================================================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         Partition layout for disk: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         Partition style          : MBR
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         MBR signature: 53033256
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         Number of partitions     : 3
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Number: 1
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Type: 7
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Boot: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Style: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Offset: 1048576
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Length: 524288000
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Drive: None
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition1
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Number: 2
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Type: 7
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Boot: No
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Style: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Offset: 525336576
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Length: 79455782912
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Drive: C:\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition2
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Number: 3
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Type: 39
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                                Boot: No
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Style: 0
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Offset: 79982622720
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Length: 542868480
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{03293928-0000-0000-00f8-559f12000000}\
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                               Drive: None
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition3
2021-09-28 10:10:50, Info                         ===========================================================
```

`bcdedit`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {001e9bbb-213d-11eb-b4bb-f2d0ce0f2b87}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {1cac28c7-213d-11eb-8bd4-98ea449f7573}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {001e9bbb-213d-11eb-b4bb-f2d0ce0f2b87}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MBR2GPT may be failing because of bad boot entries. Please add to your post the output of `bcdedit` in a Command Prompt that is run as Admin. Add also a screenshot of the entire window of Device Management. (Add to any answering comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Updated. I'm not sure if it's normal, but the recovery partition doesn't look right.

Comment: Try this: Run CMD as Admin and run `diskpart`. Drill down to the C: partition by `list disk` and `select disk #` and `list partition` and `select partition #`. Use the command `detail partition` to see if it's marked as "Active No", and if so type the `Active` command.

Comment: I am fairly certain that `/allowfullos` only lets you run the program outside of recovery mode and doesn't actually let you convert the disk with the currently running OS.